# Delete labels from bootstrap toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I using bootstrap toggle

Here is code

```
<div id="switcher" class="doctors-appointment">
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Column">
            <b>Doctor's appointment</b>
        </div>
        <div class="Column">
            <input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-width="30" data-height="30">
        </div>
        <div class="Column">
            <b>For internal purposes</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it generates into this

```
<div class="toggle-group"><label class="btn btn-primary toggle-on" style="line-height: 20px;"></label><label class="btn btn-default active toggle-off" style="line-height: 20px;"></label><span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default"></span></div>
```

As you can see in labels are `on` and `off` text. I need to delete it.

How I can do this?

Comment: do you want to add custom text?

Comment: nope I need toggle without text @NarenMurali

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set this up with the javascript api. You can specify any text for the "on" and "off" conditions. The text is set to "On" and "Off" by default. Just set them both to blank strings:

```
  $(function() {
    $('#toggle-event').bootstrapToggle({
      on: '',
      off: ''
    });
  })
```

Comment: `$(...).bootstrapToggle is not a function`

Have this

Answer (score 2):

You can set `visibility:hidden` for the label, you need to set class `disable-labels`. Refer the below jsfiddle.

**Fiddle:** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/6qh4yfnu/2/)

**CSS:**

```
body { margin: 10px }

.disable-labels .toggle-group .toggle-on,.disable-labels .toggle-group .toggle-off{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```